# The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression. LINQ does not evaluate the expression and program terminates without any exception

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I am working on a solution using .net core 6 and contains a webapi and a console application. The data access layer is built using the repository pattern and it is a common library. we receive the OrderID from third party service which needs to be updated against each transactionID using a console application.
Below is the sample code from TestEntityRepository.cs class

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateDetailsAsync(string transactionID, string orderID)
    {
        try
        {
            var existingRec = await dbSet.Where(x => x.TransactionID == transactionID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();            
            if (existingRec != null)
            {
                existingRec.OrderID = orderID;                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {            
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The expression evaluates when used from the webapi. However, when using in the console app, the program terminates without throwing any exception. When we watch the data using the Quick watch, the value observed is [image: LINQ][image: dbSetValues]

The data could be seen from the dbSet.
I am trying to understand why it is failing to find the records from LINQ.
Could someone help me to understand the issue here please.

It's Great to have the solution ! :) Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the expressions you write won't evaluate when debugged; c'est la vie. For such a trivial query there's really only one explanation; your data store doesn't contain any transactions with ID "1111"

Comment: Hi, I have checked from the database that the record exists. Also, when I observe the dbSet for each record, it does contain the record at the index 22.

Comment: Instead of evaluating the expression, evaluate existingRec

Comment: Show me a screenshot of this case where all the dbSet including index 22 is showing in the debugger, and the Transactionid 1111 is clearly visible, and then show me the LINQ query that says its null

Comment: Hi Caius, Please refer to the screenshot showing the value of "1111" updated with the question. I tried to evaluate the expression using Immediate window, dbSet.Where(x => x.TransactionID == "1111").FirstOrDefaultAsync()
The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression
dbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TransactionID == "1111")
The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression

Comment: Hi, This seems to be working,  dbSet.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.TransactionID == "1111"); But could not understand why the other expression does not evaluate.

Comment: Does the debugger support async methods? It seems there can be lots of issues with trying to evaluate an async expression in the immediate window.

Comment: Well, I was just trying find out the issue somehow as it did not throw any exception and just terminated the program. But now I have got it working by using the ToList() in the LINQ query like dbSet.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.TransactionID == "1111")
Thanks a lot everyone for your help! Much appreciated!! :)